# Zend_Translate: Is there an easy way to use traditional plural translating in Zend_View?

Tags: zend-framework

We all know that you can call `$this->translate()` within your zend view to translate a string. However, is there also such a shortcut for **plural translating** in traditional form (so that poedit can read it) or do I have to go via `Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->plural()`?

Comment: Found out that I could write my own helper for it (as translate is a helper itself), but maybe you already know an existing implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by calling `getTranslator()` within the view:

```
$this->translate()->getTranslator()->plural('singular', 'plural', $count);
```